# nvidia-prime not installable and NVIDIA card not detected under Ubuntu12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-prime

I had installed NVIDIA drivers along with nvidia prime on Ubuntu 12.04, to run CUDA-based applications in a first time. Then, I created a mess on the system because I installed Bumblebee as well, but I was not aware about the incompatibility issues between Bumblebee and nvidia prime. As a result, nothing more worked. Now I would like to recover the previous configuration.

However, if I type on terminal `lspci | grep -i vga` the only output item is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

that is the inner intel chipset of my laptop. As you see, the NVIDIA graphic card does not appear (of course it did when everything worked). I also tried to install the `nvidia-340` driver, but after the reboot the system does not detect the card yet.

In addition, but I don't know if it is correlated, I'm not able to install `nvidia-prime` anymore. When I try to do that, the output is:

```
Package nvidia-prime is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available 
from another source

E: Package nvidia-prime has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone knows where the issue lies?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for the graphics drivers ppa although your distro maybe to old, 14.04 is well supported for cuda